# OpenVPN server employees and customers config on the same instance and server?

Tags: openvpn

I want to add some firewall rules for my customers and others for the employees.

From my understanding I can do that using different subnet combined with the `client-config-dir ccd`
Also from my understanding the client-config-dir is based on the CN.
When I tested that I discovered that I can only have one certificat by CN. And I don't want my employees nor my customers to use the same certificat so this solution seems wrong from my POV.

I know how to setup the firewall rules. What I don't is how to configure openvpn in order to use two differents "profile" to assign an different IP plage or subnet using individual certificate.

Scripts used for clients creations :

```
if [[ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "This config needs to be run with superuser privileges."
        exit
fi
new_client () {
        # Generates the custom client.ovpn
        {
        cat /etc/openvpn/server/client-common.txt
        echo "<ca>"
        cat /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
        echo "</ca>"
        echo "<cert>"
        sed -ne '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,$ p' /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/issued/"$client".crt
        echo "</cert>"
        echo "<key>"
        cat /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/private/"$client".key
        echo "</key>"
        echo "<tls-crypt>"
        sed -ne '/BEGIN OpenVPN Static key/,$ p' /etc/openvpn/server/tc.key
        echo "</tls-crypt>"
        } > /openvpn-clients-files/"$client".ovpn
}
while getopts u: flag
do
        case "${flag}" in
                u) unsanitized_client=${OPTARG};;
        esac
done
if [ -z "$unsanitized_client" ]; then
        echo "-u option followed by the username is required."
        exit
fi

echo "Username: $unsanitized_client";
client=$(sed 's/[^0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-]/_/g' <<< "$unsanitized_client")
if [[ -z "$client" || -e /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/issued/"$client".crt ]]; then
        echo "$client: invalid name."
        exit
fi
cd /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/
EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE=3650 ./easyrsa build-client-full "$client" --req-cn=interne  nopass
#EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE=3650 ./easyrsa build-client-full "interne"  nopass
# Generates the custom client.ovpn
new_client
echo
echo "$client added. Configuration available in: /openvpn-clients-files/$client.ovpn"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same CN for everybody defeats strenghts of OpenVPN. It is generally intended to be used with a unique client certificate/key for each connection. I don't get why they ever still support this "single certificate" mode, because generating certificates is cheap and easy and this way you get better security and control. I never use this `duplicate-cn`, so I don't ever know how to differentiate them in this case. If you are ready to rethink your approach to the OpenVPN, please read further.

As of original question, there could be at least two solutions.

A CCD directory is indexed by the certificate CN. You can set a "static" IP address for each client by adding a clause `push "ifconfig <local-ip> <remote-ip>"` into it's CCD file. This way you will know in advance who gets which VPN IP address, so you can build firewall rules ahead of time. It is wise to collect all similar-purpose addresses into some "pools" which are split at subnet boundary, so you'll have much less firewall rules. For example, if you use `192.168.128.0/24` block for the VPN, you will generally use `192.168.128.0/30` block for the server, so dedicate `192.168.128.4÷124/30` blocks for your employees and the rest, `192.168.128.128÷252/30` for customers. This way you'll be able to define unique addresses for 31 employee and 32 customers, then you add two firewall rules for `192.168.128.0/25` block where all employees live and for `192.168.128.128/25` where all customers live. Please note I assume `net30` topology mode here, it's easy to adjust this approach for other topology.

Another way, probably more flexible, it to use OpenVPN scripting ability. It can run user-defined scripts on some events. It passes some information about the connection to the called script. That certainly includes certificate's CN and other DN fields, which can be used in the script to differentiate clients. Read `man openvpn` for more. You can use `client-connect` and `client-disconnect` hooks, which could install and remove firewall rules dynamically. In Linux best way is to define some IP sets and install rules which use these sets beforehand, and then let OpenVPN scripts to add and remove client IP address to appropriate set on connect or disconnect event.

Comment: What I failed to understand at the time I wrote this post is that I can create a folder with the push ifconfig for every customer. I'll go with this because I'm familiar with this technique. For the story I used to have 2 VPN servers with one certificate per server. One for the customer and one for employees. I used the  duplicate-cn option. But two employees left and we had to change every employees certificates. On the other hand if a customer leave the pain is even greater. I think I know what I have to do and will give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your script assigns the same CN ("interne") to all of the issued certificates. If you passed the `--req-cn="$user"` switch instead of `--req-cn=interne`, you could differentiate between your users, so you could create client configs based on usernames.